# Would like Unix CP command to be PIPEd

Tags: unix, command, pipe, stdout, cp

I have a requirement to use the CP command to copy a file. I would like to PIPE the output to another command. I know the CP command does not have STDOUT to do this. So I can't do this through the front door.(using standard CP or PIPE) Again I must use the CP command. I have no choice here.

In my searches I did see someone was saying that the CP command can be wrapped in a script. The example they used was:

```
$foo = $( cp /u/me/test.txt)
echo "$foo"
```

As you can guess I couldn't get this to work. Does anyone have a way to put the CP outfile to STDOUT?

Comment: Are you trying to get `cp` to behave like `cat`?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use `cp` as if it were `cat`. You can mimic `cat` with

```
cp /u/me/test.txt /dev/stdout
```

Note that if you test this at an interactive terminal you may be prompted `cp: overwrite '/dev/stdout'?`. If so, it's because you have `cp` aliased to `cp -i`. In a script this won't happen.

Comment: You are right CAT would be perfect. It does a copy to STDOUT. The problem is that I have a limitation that I must use CP. The copy to STDOUT is preferred as it's copied to memory rather than disk.  If I run the command  cp /u/me/test.txt /dev/stdout it would do a copy to the file STDOUT. What I'm looking for is a copy to STDOUT so I can PIPE it to another command.

Comment: When you write to `/dev/stdout` it writes to standard out. It's a special file.

Comment: I got a permission denied message (read only). I looked into  /dev/stdout it's part of gawk and awk. This is standard to all unix systems. I'll ask my adin why this is locked down. This does look like the perfect answer thanks for you help.